# Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() method gives different path in different type of C# project

Tags: c#

While using in Console App(.Net core) the path gives up to current project folder.

For example:

```
C:\Users\ABC-PC\source\repos\Project1\
```

and while using Console App (.Net Framework) path gives up to current project debug folder.

For example:

```
C:\Users\ABC-PC\source\repos\Project1\bin\Debug\
```

My question is how can I get the path up to

```
C:\Users\ABC-PC\source\repos\Project1\
```

in console app (.Net Framework)? Is there any predefined method for it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please show your coding differences - as I dont undstand the different uses of path...

Comment: Btw you do know that bin\debug is where your exe is right - so that is the path of the exe

Comment: `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()` returns the _current working directory_ of your process. Framework console apps are build into and run from the `.\bin\debug` folder (in debug mode), but .net core console apps are (afaik) build into and startet from the source (project) directory. Which path you want to retrieve depends of course on what your app should do in production. If you actually don't want the current working directory, then don't use this method but some kind of configuration or whatever determines the path you need.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. but I don't want path up to the .\bin\debug folder. I want path up to source(project) directory in Console App(.Net Framework)

Comment: Unless you plan to deploy your entire project to the user's machine, who ever does, you should not solve this problem the way you want to.  Ensure that the files you need to run your program are properly copied into the build directory.  Either add them to the project so they can be copied or use xcopy in a post-build event.

Comment: Is there any predefined method to call up to the source(project) directory or any solution for this???

Answer (score 0):

Can't post comments yet - and I strongly advise to follow [René Vogt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5528593/ren%C3%A9-vogt)  suggestions.

But

If you wan't a really (w)hacky solution you could simply use the path you get from Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() as Input to a [`DirectoryInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo.aspx) - Instance and check if you're in the `[Release|Debug]\bin` Directory.

This object also gives you methods to query the directories content (in form of [`FileInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.aspx) objects) to check for the file you are looking for:

1. look if File is in this dir, if not
2. look if parent is not null nor file-root
3. rinse and repeat with parent till found or parent is null
4. skip searching